# Switch the serverUrl for TFS command line

Tags: tfs

I want to discard some changesets from my merge list.
Found that I need to do the following:

> tf merge "$/sourcePath/Main/Data" "$/targetPath/Branches/BranchA/Data"
>   /discard /recursive /version:C20144~C20666

I have two tfs connections: One to my company's on premise and another my personal on visualstudio.com.

When I run the above command, it opens MS sign in dialog to connect to my online account.

How do I make sure I can connect to my on premise TFS?

Answer (score 0):

Try to run `tf settings connections /switchuser http://<server>:8080/tfs` before merge command.

[image]

Comment: settings is not recognized commands. I don't see it in the list of available commands for tf

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to the folder that your On Premise TFS workspace mapped to and then run tf merge command. It will detect the server URL automatically.